# FireStore and FireStorage rules

Tags: firebase, google-cloud-firestore, firebase-security

I want to allow the user Crud access to  a file, only if the folder name in firebase storage equals to user's email address, and access to FireStore documents only if collection name equals to user's email address. How can I achieve that?

```html
rules_version = '2';
service cloud.firestore {
  match /databases/{database}/documents {
    match /{document=**} {
      allow read, write: if request.auth != null  && database==request.auth.token.email ;
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: Securing on email address is somewhat of an anti-pattern (as they tend to change), so the Firebase documentation shows a different approach to securing owner-only access: https://firebase.google.com/docs/rules/basics#content-owner_only_access. --- If you really want to secure on email address after all, can you [show us what you tried](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)?

Comment: Please edit your question and add the information Frank asked for, and please also respond using @.

Comment: @AlexMamo Edited.

Comment: Where are you storing the folder name in Firebase Storage?